# Why does my Java Binary Search Tree class not actually remove nodes when I tell it to?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I'm building a Binary Search Tree in Java to better understand how they work, and I'm working on the function to remove a node with a specific value.

I basically iterate through the tree until I find the node with the correct value, and then based on how many children it has act accordingly.

If it has no children, I set it to null. If it has one I set itself equal to the child. If it has two, I go through the left tree, following left until I get to the left, then delete that and set the value of the node I was on to the value of the deleted node.

```
class BTree {
    public int data;
    public BTree leftTree;
    public BTree rightTree;

    public BTree(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public BTree(int data, BTree leftTree, BTree rightTree) {
        this.data = data;
        this.leftTree = leftTree;
        this.rightTree = rightTree;
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        if (data < this.data) {
            if (this.leftTree == null) {
                BTree newTree = new BTree(data);
                this.leftTree = newTree;
            } else {
                insert(this.leftTree, data);
            }
        } else {
            if (this.rightTree == null) {
                BTree newTree = new BTree(data);
                this.rightTree = newTree;
            } else {
                insert(this.rightTree, data);
            }
        }
    }

    private void insert(BTree tree, int data) {
        if (tree.data == data) {
            return;
        }

        if (data < tree.data) {
            if (tree.leftTree == null) {
                BTree newTree = new BTree(data);
                tree.leftTree = newTree;
            } else {
                insert(tree.leftTree, data);
            }
        } else {
            if (tree.rightTree == null) {
                BTree newTree = new BTree(data);
                tree.rightTree = newTree;
            } else {
                insert(tree.rightTree, data);
            }
        }
    }

    public void inorderTraversal(BTree tree) {
        if (tree.leftTree != null) {
            inorderTraversal(tree.leftTree);
        }

        System.out.print(tree.data + ", ");

        if (tree.rightTree != null) {
            inorderTraversal(tree.rightTree);
        }
    }

    public void remove(int data, BTree tree) {
        if (tree == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (data == tree.data) {
            if (tree.leftTree != null && tree.rightTree != null) {
                int minimumValue = getMinimumValue(tree.leftTree);
                remove(minimumValue, tree);

                tree.data = minimumValue;
            } else if (tree.leftTree != null) {
                tree = tree.leftTree;
            } else if (tree.rightTree != null) {
                tree = tree.rightTree;
            } else {
                tree = null;
            }
        } else if (data < tree.data) {
            remove(data, tree.leftTree);
        } else {
            remove(data, tree.rightTree);
        }
    }

    public int getMinimumValue(BTree tree) {
        if (tree.leftTree == null) {
            return tree.data;
        } else {
            return getMinimumValue(tree.leftTree);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BTree myTree = new BTree(5);
        myTree.insert(6);
        myTree.insert(12);
        myTree.insert(4);
        myTree.insert(3);
        myTree.insert(6);
        myTree.insert(15);
        myTree.insert(1);
        myTree.insert(9);
        myTree.insert(-2);

        myTree.remove(3, myTree);

        myTree.inorderTraversal(myTree);
    }
}
```

Despite this, 3 still shows up in the inorder traversal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `class Test {static void remove(int n) {n = 0;} public static void main(String[] args) {int m = 5; remove(m); System.out.println(m);}}` print and why?

Comment: @immibis Fair enough, I'm guessing Java passes my value and not by reference, but then how does my `insert()` function work? Wouldn't it be just inserting the nodes into local copies of the tree in the function?

Comment: Java passes references by value. That sounds confusing, but that means that in `void x(MyClass m) {...}` and `MyClass o = new MyClass(); x(o);`, `o` contains a reference to an object - which is copied - but the object it refers to is not copied.

Comment: @DougSmith. `insert` works on `tree.leftTree` and `tree.rightTree`, so it is changing the state *inside* `tree`. This will be seen at the calling site. `remove` tries to change the reference value of `tree` itself, which won't work due to pass-by-value: internal state mutations to parameters are seen; reference changes to the parameter itself are not

Answer (score 3):

Take this line as an example:

```
tree = tree.leftTree;
```

You are trying to rewrite the tree by assigning a new value to `tree`.

But `tree` is a method parameter. By reassigning it inside the method, you are not reassigning the method argument at the point of the method call: **method parameters are passed by value, always**. This means that a reference type argument is passed by value, as the value of the reference. Changes to that value (the reference) inside the method have no effect at the original calling site. Changes to the *contents* of that reference type will have an effect.

It is worth quoting The Java Tutorials > Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor > [Passing Reference Data Type Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

> Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into methods **by value**. This means that when the method returns, the passed-in reference **still references the same object as before**. However, the **values of the object's fields can be changed** in the method

Look at this simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a1 = new A();
  System.out.println("before the method                 : " + a1);
  reassignFail(a1);
  System.out.println("after the method                  : " + a1);
}
static void reassignFail(A a1) {
  A a2 = new A();
  System.out.println("inside the method a2              : " + a2);
  a1 = a2;
  System.out.println("inside the method for parameter a1: " + a1);
}
static class A{
  int id;
  private static int iid;
  public A() { id = ++iid; }
  public String toString() { return "this is instance " + id; }
}
```

This prints:

```
before the method                 : this is instance 1
inside the method a2              : this is instance 2
inside the method for parameter a1: this is instance 2
after the method                  : this is instance 1
```

So your reassignment has no effect on the tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your second insert looks weird to me, as you only need to create a new BTree with data or just use the same insert you are already in to handle all the posible cases. The same goes for inOrderTraversal.

And for remove you need to return a BTree, to handle the cases where the "this" reference is the one you want removed (you can't asign to "this").

```
class BTree {

    public int data;
    public BTree leftTree;
    public BTree rightTree;

    public BTree(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public BTree(int data, BTree leftTree, BTree rightTree) {
        this.data = data;
        this.leftTree = leftTree;
        this.rightTree = rightTree;
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        if (this.data == data) {
            return;
        }

        if (data < this.data) {
            if (leftTree == null) {
                leftTree = new BTree(data);
            } else {
                leftTree.insert(data);
            }
        } else {
            if (this.rightTree == null) {
                rightTree = new BTree(data);
            } else {
                rightTree.insert(data);
            }
        }
    }

    public void inOrderTraversal() {
        if (leftTree != null) {
            leftTree.inOrderTraversal();
        }

        System.out.print(data + ", ");

        if (rightTree != null) {
            rightTree.inOrderTraversal();
        }
    }

    //the void equivalents are in comments
    public BTree remove(int data) {
        if (data == this.data) {
            if (leftTree != null && rightTree != null) {
                //this is the only legal case for the void remove.
                int minValue = getMinimumValue();
                this.data = minValue;
                //leftTree.remove(minValue); //and no return is needed
                leftTree = leftTree.remove(minValue);
                return this;
            } else if (leftTree != null) {
                //this = leftTree; //illegal
                return leftTree;
            } else if (rightTree != null) {
                //this = rightTree; //illegal
                return rightTree;
            } else {
                //this = null; //illegal
                return null;
            }
        } else if (data < this.data) {
            leftTree = leftTree.remove(data);
            return this;
        } else {
            rightTree = rightTree.remove(data);
            return this;
        }
    }

    public int getMinimumValue() {
        if (leftTree == null) {
            return data;
        } else {
            return leftTree.getMinimumValue();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BTree myTree = new BTree(5);
        myTree.insert(6);
        myTree.insert(12);
        myTree.insert(4);
        myTree.insert(3);
        myTree.insert(6);
        myTree.insert(15);
        myTree.insert(1);
        myTree.insert(9);
        myTree.insert(-2);

        myTree = myTree.remove(3);

        myTree.inOrderTraversal();
    }
}
```